# Border Animations in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I would like to create border animations in Tailwind as such (specifically the "draw circle" animation): https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY

What would be the "correct" approach here, possibly someone with experience could provide some guidance.

```
<button class="spin circle">Spin Circle</button>

.spin {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  
  &:hover {
    color: $blue;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2px solid transparent; // We're animating border-color again
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: $blue; // Show borders
    border-right-color: $blue;
    border-bottom-color: $blue;

    transition:
      border-top-color 0.15s linear, // Stagger border appearances
      border-right-color 0.15s linear 0.10s,
      border-bottom-color 0.15s linear 0.20s;
  }

  &::after {
    border: 0 solid transparent; // Makes border thinner at the edges? I forgot what I was doing
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-top: 2px solid $blue; // Shows border
    border-left-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    border-right-width: 2px; // Solid edges, invisible borders
    transform: rotate(270deg); // Rotate around circle
    transition:
      transform 0.4s linear 0s,
      border-left-width 0s linear 0.35s; // Solid edge post-rotation
  }
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
    
  &::before,
  &::after {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}
```

I would like to achieve this with existing Tailwind animation utilities if possible, however I'm currently stuck with my only perceived path being of using some pure css for this.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and give it a shot then share your attempt with Tailwind. Someone will be glad to help you if you've shown effort. Here's some tips if you're not sure where to start: Each Tailwind utility corresponds to a CSS property and base Tailwind does not support psuedo elements so for those use real elements (span, div) nested inside the parent button and give them the `aria-hidden` attribute and style with regular TW utilities. And make the button a group so you can use `group-hover` for the fake psuedo elements.